# Input Textfield validation in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm currently trying to create a form using JSF where there're two inputText, out of which only one inputText has to be entered with a value. Is there any way by which I can do this in JSF? Can one of the input boxes be disabled if I have entered a value in the other inputText? Following is my input tags that I am using to get the values. Currently the value can be entered in both the fields.

```
<p:outputLabel for="field1" value="value1: "/>
<p:inputText id="field1"> </p:inputText>

<p:outputLabel for="field2" value="value2: "/>
<p:inputText id="field2"> </p:inputText>
```

Can anyone please guide me with this?

Comment: The concept is confusing. if one of the inputTexts is disabled, and the user made a mistake by filling the first one, and wants to undo the changes, the only solution would be is to empty the filled inputText. For me this idea is not a valid approach.

Comment: I am actually just trying a way to force the user to enter value in one textbox and not both...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that works for my requirement...
I am calling a javascript function onblur of my 1st textbox and disabling the 2nd textbox. Same function is called to disable the 1st checkbox incase the 2nd input box is entered with a value.

Comment: I suggest to use as less jQuery / javascript as possible in combination with JSF to reduce the complexity and make the application more maintainable and managable for other people if you are not there. jQuery isn't the first thing developers think about when maintaining JSF applications.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`o:validateOne` by OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOne)

> The `<o:validateOne>` validates if ONLY ONE of the given UIInput
> components have been filled out.

b.t.w there is also the following (among others )validators in OmniFaces

> [validateMultiple](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple)
>
> [validateOneOrMore](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrMore)
>
> [validateOneOrNone](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateOneOrNone)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want to set the 2nd input field to "disabled" if you add some value to the first inputField without hitting a button.

You could do this with an `onkeyup=""` event in you `inputText` which calls a backingBean method that sets the second inputfield to disabled.

Example:

```
<p:outputLabel for="field1" value="value1: "/>
<p:inputText id="field1" disabled="#{backingBean.field1Disabled} 
onkeyup="#{backingBean.disableField2}" value=#{backingBean.value1}/>

<p:outputLabel for="field2" value="value2: "/>
<p:inputText id="field2" disabled="#{backingBean.field2Disabled} 
onkeyup="#{backingBean.disableField1}/>
```

you could have a method in your backingBean like:

```
public void disableField2() {
    if (value1.length() > 0) {
        field2Disabled = true;
    } else {
        field2Disabled = false;
    }
}

public void disableField1() {
    if (value2.length() > 0) {
        field1Disabled = true;
    } else {
        field1Disabled = false;
    }
}
```